# How can check if a variable is equal to another whilst using try parse?

Tags: c#

I made a program to check if a users pin is correct but it will only check it if the pin is an integer. Is there anyway to make this code more efficient by maybe using only 1 while loop?

```
int pin;
int realPin = 1111;
Console.Write("What's the pin: ");
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pin)){
    Console.Write("Please enter a 4 numbers please: ");
}
while(pin != realPin){
    Console.Write("Wrong Password: ");
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pin)){
        Console.Write("Please enter 4 numbers please: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to trace your code?

Comment: If you're really just concerned about efficiency (how many CPU cycles this takes up), I can't imagine this taking up any significant amount of CPU time.

Comment: Your question boils down to "how can I use boolean logic to combine two operations"; the answer would be to use `&&`, `||` etc.  For instance, `while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pin) && pin.Equals(realPin))) { Console.Write("Enter your PIN"); }`

Comment: @AdeStringer Thank you, that was what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

when you find yourself writing duplicate code, you should consider moving the duplicated code to a new method you can reuse:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int realPin = 1111;

    Console.Write("What's the pin: ");

    var pin = GetUserInput();
    while (pin != realPin)
    {
        Console.Write("Wrong Password: ");
        pin = GetUserInput();
    }
}

public static int GetUserInput()
{
    int pin;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pin))
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a 4 numbers please: "
    }

    return pin;
}
```

the code isn't more efficient in terms of performance, but it is factored in a more DRY fashion

Comment: you can simplify it by `while (GetUserInput() != realPin)`

Comment: that's true, once the condition is good you know the pin is your hardcoded `1111` afterwards

Comment: oh. missed that `pin`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *separating* syntax errors (e.g. `bla-bla-bla` input) and wrong password tries `1234`:

```
  int realPin = 1111;

  while (true) {
    int pin; 

    do {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter a 4 numbers please: ");
    }
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pin)); 

    if (pin == realPin)
      break;

    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Password");
  }

  // unlocked
```

However, you can combine them into the single loop:

```
  int realPin = 1111;
  int pin;

  do {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a 4 numbers please: ");
  }
  while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pin) || (pin != realPin));

  // unlocked
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to convert the value to an integer at all, it's easier just to compare strings, so you might as well fall back to performing a single test.  This also means that input like `000001111` won't be accepted, which seems valid since your question relates to PIN validation.

Here's how I'd do what you've outlined:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Slightly over-engineered :)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rawInput;
        while (true)
        {
            rawInput = ReadPin();

            // No need to attempt parsing to an integer, as the PIN isn't stored as an integer
            bool isValid = Securityish.ValidatePin(rawInput);

            // If user has entered a valid PIN, break out of the loop ...
            if (isValid)
                break;

            // ... otherwise let them know that they're entered an invalid or incorrect PIN
            Console.WriteLine("That value is incorrect...");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Unlocked, press any key to continue");
        Console.Read();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads user input and masks to prevent accidental disclosure of the user's PIN
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ReadPin()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter your PIN: ");

        string input = "";
        while (true)
        {
            // Read all key presses
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();

            // If user has pressed enter, it's time to return the accumulated input, so bust out of this loop
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                // Allow deletion of PIN characters
                if (input.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(" \b");
                    input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // The last character is a space, just put it back again then wait for further input
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }

                continue;
            }

            // Function keys etc. return a null character
            if (key.KeyChar == '\0')
            {
                // Overwrite with a blank character, then move backwards to where we were in the first place
                Console.Write("\b \b");
                continue;
            }

            input += key.KeyChar;

            // Mask input
            Console.Write("\b*");
        }

        // Add blank line to keep input clean
        Console.WriteLine();
        return input;
    }
}

internal static class Securityish
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compares a supplied value against a secret PIN and returns whether the values match
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pin"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static bool ValidatePin(string pin)
    {
        // Might be better to use one way hashing here
        return pin != null && pin.Equals(UnlockCode);
    }

    // TODO: Make this read a value from file, database, somewhere
    private static string UnlockCode { get { return "1111"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop if you initialise `pin` and convert it to a nullable int:

```
int? pin = null;
int enteredPin;
int realPin = 1111;
while(pin != realPin)
{
    if (pin.HasValue)
    {
        Console.Write("Wrong Password: ");
    }
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out enteredPin))
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter 4 numbers please: ");
    }
    pin = enteredPin;
}
```

As initially pin != realPin your code will enter your loop and because it doesn't have a value you won't output the error message.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try:

```
        int pin;
        int realPin = 1111;
        Console.Write("What's the pin: ");
        foreach (var item in Console.ReadLine())
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out pin))
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a 4 numbers please: ");
            }
            if (pin.ToString().Length == 4)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a 4 numbers please: ");
            }
            else if (pin != realPin)
            {
                Console.Write("Wrong Password: ");

            }
        }
```

Comment: your `foreach` will iterate over characters of user input.